# JMeter: How can I hit multiple users in different threadgroup at once

Tags: multithreading, timer, jmeter

I am trying to load multiple users from different ThreadGroup who are suppose to hit 3 different URLs at once with following scenario:

```
Test Plan
  Synchronizing Timer (Number of simulated users to group by is: 100)
  ThreadGroup 1(40 Users)
  ThreadGroup 2(20 Users)
  ThreadGroup 3(40 Users)
```

Is the above scenario correct to proceed with Synchronizing Timer as common timer with Total count of all ThreadGroup Users i.e: 40+20+40=100?

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your 100 Users to hit the server at nearly exactly the same time then yes.
Note you would end up having very short delay between each set of 100 hits.
So you need to be sure this is realistic.

If you only want to simulate 100 Users running 3 types of URLs then there is no need for Synchronizing Timer here, use other timers like Gaussian Random Timer for example.